# My MySQL JOIN query only gets data from one table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

```
SELECT `users`.*
FROM (`users`)
JOIN `users_profiles` ON `users_profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `users_sites` ON `users_sites`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`id` = 4
```

That's my query. I have data in `users`, `users_profiles`, `albums`, and `users_sites`. Currently I'm getting the necessary data in four separate queries but I want to optimise with `JOIN`s.

My problem is that the result set being returned only contains one row of data from the `users` table (where the `id` is 4). This is to be expected but I want other tables `JOIN`ed on the end too.

For example, `users_profiles` contains a row that I have confirmed contains `user_id` set to 4. But no rows from `users_profiles` is ever added to the query, all I see is what comes from `users`.

Any ideas? It's the same case for the other tables - I've confirmed they *should* be selected properly but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want rows for users even if there are no albums for them? What about if there are no users_sites for them? Will you have multiple albums and multiple users_sites for one user?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder - just tested the (working) version on a user with no albums, and it returns 0 rows. I've changed the 4th line of my query to `LEFT JOIN` to retain it.

Comment: I ask because if you allow both multiple albums and multiple users_sites, then you're probably not going to get what you want with this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT `users`.*, `users_profiles`.*, `albums`.*, `users_sites`.*
FROM (`users`)
JOIN `users_profiles` ON `users_profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `users_sites` ON `users_sites`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`id` = 4
```

Your code only selecting the columns from users table.

Alternatively,

```
SELECT *
FROM (`users`)
JOIN `users_profiles` ON `users_profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `users_sites` ON `users_sites`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`id` = 4
```

Please beware that selecting * is not recommended as it is not optimized. Just select the column that you need.

Comment: Thanks, your first query works great. I'll look into optimising the column selection.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `users`.*, `user_profiles`.*, `albums`.*, `user_sites`.*
FROM (`users`)
JOIN `users_profiles` ON `users_profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `users_sites` ON `users_sites`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`id` = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You only select the columns from your users table;

`SELECT users.*`

Change your `SELECT` statement to include the columns you want to retrieve, to include **all columns from all tables** (affected by your query);

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
JOIN `users_profiles` ON `users_profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `users_sites` ON `users_sites`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`id` = 4
```

To include everything from the **users_profile and users** tables;

```
SELECT `users`.*, `users_profiles`.* FROM `users`
JOIN `users_profiles` ON `users_profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `users_sites` ON `users_sites`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`id` = 4
```